# WoW download problem

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I never played World of Warcraft before. So I thought I will give it a shot and tried to download the 'Starter Edition' which lets you play for free up to level 20 from my Battle.net account.
  But after clicking the 'Game Installer', it only downloads the client. It doesn't even start the launcher. 
  So I saw an Youtube video on how to download the Starter Edition. It shows that the game launcher automatically starts after downloading the client. But in my case, it doesn't happen.
  The Battle.net account says-"Oops, sorry. We couldn't find what we wanted to show you." So what to do? 
  I live in India. Is the game playable at all from India?

Comment: Are you registered? There is a support page on the battle net site. Like this: https://eu.battle.net/support/en/ (but this is for Europe)

Comment: Registered in what? I already have a Battle.net account.

Comment: did you try actually running the downloaded game launcher directly?

Comment: There is no launcher like that. It only downloads the battle.net desktop client app. The game installer doesn't run.

Comment: So did you run the game client, then.. the part that installed but didnt open manually? If you mean "i did but it wont run", what happens when you run it?

Comment: It shows the message written in the question. And in the down right corner appears-"Fetching Encoding Table..." .

Comment: You wait for it to finish downloading, and then click Play.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you got the first steps right; Log into your account in their website and search for the menu to download game clients. There you will find the WoW installer (which will actually install the battle.net launcher) and then you simply install it.

After installing it, you will now be able to open the battle.net launcher (which requires you to log in with your e-mail and password) that enable you to actually download and install any current Blizzard games, including WoW.

To my knowledge there is no restriction on Blizzard's end in any of these steps to someone playing from an India IP, though local legislation may still apply.

Comment: Oh wow... this was a long time ago. I got it to work. Thanks for replying :)